# How can i fix it? Card out of DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to list side by side an anime list with images and name on a card, but the DIV ends and the image ignores and continues, how can I solve this?

URL: [Here](http://myanimeapi.000webhostapp.com/)

Image: [The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4dMW.png)

css:

```
.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    min-width: 199px;
    max-width: 200px;
    float:left;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
    <button class="btn btn-success add" onclick="novoEpisodio(85)"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Adicionar Episódio</button>
                <img onclick="escolherAnime(85)" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-TYMOypUwSGI/WcqOASxepZI/AAAAAAAAK2w/-_V0RHPcEj8d0IO79AyUf2oUFTRRa3TjgCLcBGAs/s1600/Black-Clover-anime-poster-visual-v1.jpg" style="min-width:199px; max-width:200px; min-height:299px; max-height: 300px;">
                <div class="container">
                  <h4><b>Black Clover</b>

                  </h4>

                </div>
                 </div>
```

Comment: you should try to replace your `container` by a `row` => because a container has a fixed width....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're site's Bootstrap version is out of date with the HTML syntax you're using. **Cards** replaced panels from **Bootstrap 3**. You're using **Bootstrap 3**, [view here](http://prntscr.com/ltnfxp) which uses panels.

A lot of things changed between Bootstrap 3 and 4. I  highly recommend you go with **Bootstrap 4**. Additionally, your HTML syntax doesn't line up with the traditional layout.

```
container > row > column > card
```

Here is a **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/newnam/pen/WLvRqg)** you can fork and play with.

Here is an example of what you need using Bootstrap 4.

```css
/* Roboto Font */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


/* Custom CSS */
.text-strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.card-body {
  padding: .5rem;
}

.card-title {
  margin: 0;
}

.card {
  border: 2px dashed black;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px rgba(150,150,150,.5);
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px  rgba(60, 141, 188,0.5);
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'></script>

<div class="container-fluid p-5">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.anitube.site/wp-content/uploads/Bleach-dub.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-strong">Bleach</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.anitube.site/wp-content/uploads/Bleach-dub.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-strong">Black Clover</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.anitube.site/wp-content/uploads/Bleach-dub.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-strong">Boku dake ga in...</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.anitube.site/wp-content/uploads/Bleach-dub.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-strong">Dragon Ball Super</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.anitube.site/wp-content/uploads/Bleach-dub.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-strong">Nanatsu no Taizai</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-flex align-items-stretch mb-2">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.anitube.site/wp-content/uploads/Bleach-dub.jpg">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-strong">Naruto Shippuden</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```